# Incompatible types java repository

Tags: java, spring, repository

Hi everyone i have problem with my code

Model:

```
package my.taco.models;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Taco {
    private Long id;
    private Date createdAt;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Problem is in the jdbc repository in this part of code

```
 for(Ingredient ingredient : taco.getIngredients()){
           saveIngredientToTaco(ingredient,tacoId);
       }
```

Problem description:

> Incompatible types. Found: 'my.taco.models.Ingredient', required:
> 'java.lang.String'

Comment: Can you please show more details of your saveIngredientToTaco method?

Comment: Are you sure you want ingredients to be a `List<String>` and not a `List<Ingredient>` ?

Comment: @MarcoTizzano i think this is not necessary the problem is in line in for ( Ingredint ingredient: taco.getIngredients())

Comment: @Powerlord yes this work actually thanks but this model code is from book "Spring in Action Fifth Edition" maybe this is just mistake in code in book

Comment: This doesn`t work at all i have now problem in another part of code if i change this the view give me errors